# cannot import name same_origin from authentication.py tastypie django

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why I am getting a "ImportError: cannot import name same_origin"

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from
_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
File "/var/www/will/agora/agora/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bin.resources import QuestionResourse, UserResource, ResponseResourse
  File "/var/www/will/agora/bin/resources.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tastypie-0.12.2-py2.7.egg/tastypie/resources.py", line
20, in <module>
    from tastypie.authentication import Authentication
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tastypie-0.12.2-py2.7.egg/tastypie/authentication.py",
line 11, in <module>
    from django.utils.http import same_origin
ImportError: cannot import name same_origin
```

My installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bin',
    'tastypie',
}
```

What other information would be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `same_origin` method was removed from django as of version 1.9. You can [look at the commit here](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b0c56b895fd2694d7f5d4595bdbbc41916607f45#diff-60f461827b74beaf0ea54cb211e5e4dd).

It looks like this was fixed in tastypie [as of v0.13.0](https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/commit/983b3aae9393779a61333a66c0807cdc5d48d7d6#diff-9e4250a1d49d64639ae9cea1fb5ef002).

Also, tastypie v0.12 doesn't support django 1.9, [but v0.13 does](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release_notes/v0.13.0.html). Upgrade tastypie by running:

```
$ pip install django-tastypie==0.13.3
```

*And if you have a `requirements.txt` file, be sure to update the version number there as well.*

Comment: Thank you this worked! Although I had to use the command `pip install django-tastypie==0.13.3`

Answer (score 1):

django.utils.http doesn't have a same_origin function (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/)

Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/clickjacking/